# Getting this object name inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my JavaScript:

```
function drinkable(name, price, effect, heal, alcohol){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.effect = effect;
    this.heal = heal;
    this.alcohol = alcohol;
    this.use = function(position){
        satisfy(thirst,this.effect,"#thirst");
        inventory.splice(position, 1); updateInventory();
        alcoholLevel = alcoholLevel + this.alcohol; updateAlcohol();
        changeHP(this.heal); checkHP();
    };
};
// DRINKABLES - name, price, thirst, HP, alcohol
var d1 = new drinkable("Bottled Water", 0.84, 15, 0, 0);
var d2 = new drinkable("Raush Juice", 0.90, 15, 1, 0);
var d3 = new drinkable("Vodka Alosuth", 2.70, 5, -15, 1.2);
```

But I have a problem with new function I created:

```
function store(name, description, goods){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.goods = goods;
    this.listGoods = function(){
        var foo = "<p>"+this.name+": "+this.description+"</p><table class='table table-condensed'><tr><th>item</th><th>price</th><th></th></tr>";
        for (var i=0;i<this.goods.length;i++){
            foo = foo + ("<tr><td>"+this.goods[i].name+"</td><td>"+this.goods[i].price+"</td><td><a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory("+this.goods[i]+")</a></td></tr>"); // this line is a problem
        }
        foo = foo + "</table>";
        return foo;
    }
}
// STORES - name, description, goods
var s1 = new store(
    "24/7 Store",
    "All day, all night, every day!",
    [d1,d2,d3]
);
```

Everything in this function above works except for this:

```
+"</td><td><a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory("+this.goods[i]+")</a></td></tr>"
```

It's supossed to create this, for example:

```
<a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory(d1)'>buy</a>
```

but instead it returns this:

```
<a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory([object Object])'>buy</a>
```

How can I force it to return its variable name instead of whole object?

Comment: An object cannot and doesn't have a reference to the name of the variable it is referred by. Imagine `foobar = d1`. Which name would you expect to get now?

Comment: so the solution can be giving every drink it's ID which is same as it's var name? Like a d1.ID = "d1"?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I didn't realize what you are actually trying to do. If you want to pass the object itself to the function called in the event handler, the better solution would be to not use inline event handlers. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html and http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html.

Comment: If you want to code the handler in an attribute like that, you'll have to make `goods` available globally, which probably isn't what you want. Either that, or you'll need to serialize the entire object, then deserialize it in the function. That would be unfortunate, and won't see updates that occur to the original.

Comment: I made it working, I will post an answer how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

this.goods[i] is an object. and the object.toString function shows the following. what you want is the object variable itself

```
+"</td><td><a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory(s1.goods["+i+"])</a></td></tr>"
```

you want the ith item in the goods array of the s1 object.
A better idea would be to use unobtrusive javascript to create the element and add an event listener (or handler).

when the onClick event fires it has no idea what the context is. so you need to reference it as if it were calling from the global scope perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I added ID inside a constructor like this:

```
function drinkable(ID, name, price, effect, heal, alcohol){
    this.ID=ID;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.effect = effect;
    this.heal = heal;
    this.alcohol = alcohol;
    this.use = function(position){
        satisfy(thirst,this.effect,"#thirst");
        inventory.splice(position, 1); updateInventory();
        alcoholLevel = alcoholLevel + this.alcohol; updateAlcohol();
        changeHP(this.heal); checkHP();
    };
};
```

then I had to also update all objects

```
// DRINKABLES - name, price, thirst, HP, alcohol
var d1 = new drinkable("d1", "Bottled Water", 0.84, 15, 0, 0);
var d2 = new drinkable("d2", "Raush Juice", 0.90, 15, 1, 0);
var d3 = new drinkable("d3", "Vodka Alosuth", 2.70, 5, -15, 1.2);
```

now I just rewrote `<td><a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory("+this.goods[i]+")</a></td>` to `<td><a class='buy' onClick='buyToInventory("+this.goods[i].ID+")</a></td>`

Comment: You should check my revised comment. This is actually a bad solution. You are relying on the fact that the variable name is the same as the string value you pass to the constructor, and that the variables are global. That's difficult to maintaing because (1) if you change the variable name, you have to remember to change the string as well (2) if you change the code so that `d1`, `d2`, `d3` are not global anymore, your code will break.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot get the name of the variable you used to pass the values into your function when within the function scope.  See this post for some more details: [how to get object's name in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448135/how-to-get-objects-name-in-javascript)