# Print JSON path and variable result in one call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to console.log something like this:

`myParent.myChildData(5)`
(variable literal name + value in brackets)

from a JSON object such as this:

`{myParent: {myChildData: 5}}`

I would like to do it with referencing the object notation ideally only once. Something like:

`console.log(printExpression(myParent.myChildData))`

Where printExpression I'm certainly happy to be a generic helper function that could return this. I've searched high and low, but obviously printExpression receives the actual evaluated value and this causes a road block.

Comment: Maybe: [how to get object's name in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448135/how-to-get-objects-name-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes the name of the variable, as the text on the link says is irretrievably lost. So don't think it will bed possible. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn JSON into a JavaScript object by using `JSON.parse(jsonString)`.

You can store that as a variable and then `console.log` it.

Or you can just directly `console.log` the passed data like this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"myparent":{"myChildData": 5}}').myParent.myChildData);
```

---

### **Edit**

After understanding what exactly the helper function does, I've created a `printExpression` function that returns string values based on your example.

```js
function printExpression(object, stringBefore) {
  //Recursively make objects with keys as methods
  let newObject = {};

  for (var key in object) {
    //Make sure the key exists on the object
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      let value = object[key];
      //If the value is an object, just add a get method that returns the object
      if (typeof(value) == "object") {
        let childObject = printExpression(value, key + ".");
        newObject[key] = childObject;
      }
      //If not, make a method that returns the wanted syntax
      else {
        //Form the string based on specific syntax
        let str = key + "(" + value + ")";
        //Check if we should add stringBefore
        if (stringBefore) {
          str = stringBefore + str;
        }
        newObject[key] = str;
      }
    }
  }
  //Return the new object
  return newObject;
}

var example = printExpression(JSON.parse('{"myParent": {"myChildData": 5}}'));
console.log(example.myParent.myChildData);
```

**How It Works**
When creating the helper object, it recursively reads all the keys of the original object and makes a new object that returns the keys in an organized way. For example if the original object was `{ greeting: "hello" }` then `newObject.greeting` would be `"greeting(hello)"` (as you said it should be).

**Possible Problems**
Doesn't get updated when you change the original object. I don't think this will be much of a problem as you seem to be reading static JSON data, but just letting you know.

Comment: Thanks, but you doubled up on specifying myparent and myChildData. So that won't fly. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you're trying to do? Do you want to make a helper function that would return `5` (based on the example you gave)?

Comment: I want to print this. Not the result of it, but literally: `myParent.myChildData(5)`

Comment: Would something like `console.log(helper[myparent].myChildData])` be ok? If yes, then I know a way of making your helper function.