# jquery array-like object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following datas:

```
var formFeilds={
            'text':  {
                'T1':{'required':true,'min':25,'max':55},
                'T2':{'required':true,'min':2,'max':5}
            } 
            ,'text2':5
        };
function findObj(obj){
return key,itsobj
}
```

I want take text1, text2 Objects and their names and related objects.
For example findObj(formFeilds) would return (text,formFeilds.text AND text2,5)
also findObj(formFeilds.text)  would return (T1,formFeilds.text.T1 AND T1,formFeilds.text.T2)
I need check returned values are **object** or not in jquery

Comment: Return it as an array? Also, `5` is not an object.

Comment: Your objects don't seem very array-like to me.

Comment: No. I want return all things as exists including int,obj,text,... then I need it be checked for being object or not seperatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I need check returned values are object or not in jquery*

You can use the native Javascript `typeof` operator but keep in mind that almost everything is an object in JS except `string|boolean|number|null|undefined`.

Comment: Caveat: `typeof` thinks `null` is an object.

Comment: Yeah, JS and its things...But that's the general rule of objects

Comment: @Huseyin: Yes, `formFeilds` is an object isn't it?

Comment: @pimvdb yes it is an object with multiple contents.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're after but this quick example with your code gives me, predictably, `typeof formFields.text2 // Number` so it works...http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/zPkPV/

Comment: I need a function like as foreach in PHP

Comment: A better method to check ones type is `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`. This returns `[object internal]` where `internal` is `Array`, `Object`, `Function`, ...

Comment: **@Huseyin** check this out, it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript

Comment: **@elclanrs** that is close to mine problem. Can I have print_r() like function for my object?