# traversing through json nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, hash

Is it possible to traverse through all the nodes and find the wanted field from a complex json whose level is not predetermined

```
{
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "news",
    "_source": {
        "partnerName": "propertyFile 9",
        "relatedSources": "null",
        "entityCount": "50",
        "Categories": {
            "Types": {
                "Events": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "term": "Time",
                    "Time": [{
                        "term": "Dec 9",
                        "Dec_9": [{
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "2012"
                        }]
                        }]
                    }, {
                    "count": 4,
                    "term": "News",
                    "News": [{
                        "term": "Germany",
                        "Germany": [{
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Election"
                        }],
                        "currency": "Euro (EUR)"
                    }, {
                        "term": "Egypt",
                        "Egypt": [{
                            "count": 1,
                            "term": "Revolution"
                        }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I could get in to the first level , bt how do I go to second level if the field name is not present in the first level. This is how I started it. http://jsfiddle.net/W8qhA/1/

Comment: [Recursion](http://www.google.co.nz/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=14&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=recursion)

Comment: @penartur I want to print the output of a given field name from text box..Ivnt added the textbox in fiddle..im jst giving values manually..

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve your problem. There is some function and also a little explanation. Hope that helps you out. 
[Traverse all the Nodes of a JSON Object Tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I whipped up a function that will work on an object of the structure you presented.  If there are multiple keys of the same name it will simply return the first one it encounters.

```
var findDeepKey = function(obj, key){
    var results = [];

    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return null;

    for (var k in obj) {
        if (k === key) return obj[k];
    }

    for (var k in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
            if (obj[k].length) {
                for (var i = 0, il = obj[k].length; i < il; i++) {
                    results.push(findDeepKey(obj[k][i], key));
                }
            } else {
                for (var kk in obj[k]) {
                    if (kk === key) return obj[k][kk];
                    results.push(findDeepKey(obj[k][kk], key));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0, il = results.length; i < il; i++) {
        if (results[i] !== null) return results[i];
    }

    return null;
};
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7HsyE/)

Comment: This is exactly what Im looking for, bt how do we find all the occurence like term for example..

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx