# Parse JSON with multiple levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse this JSON that I have assigned to a javascript variable but I am having a hard time looping through it due to it having multiple levels

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var varJson = {
            "d": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Offices(100013449)",
                            "uri": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Offices(100013449)",
                            "type": "AlfWebApiInfrastructure.Poco.Office"
                        },
                        "Agency": {
                            "__deferred": {
                                "uri": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Offices(100013449)/Agency"
                            }
                        },
                        "Advertiser": {
                            "__deferred": {
                                "uri": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Offices(100013449)/Advertiser"
                            }
                        },
                        "Contacts": {
                            "results": [
                                {
                                    "__metadata": {
                                        "id": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Contacts(id=59980,jobId=1000105450)",
                                        "uri": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Contacts(id=59980,jobId=1000105450)",
                                        "type": "AlfWebApiInfrastructure.Poco.Contact"
                                    },
                                    "id": 59980,
                                    "jobId": 1000105450,
                                    "mask": 67108863,
                                    "name": "Name",
                                    "jobtitle": "Job Title",
                                    "email": "email",
                                    "companyType": "companyType",
                                    "companyId": 1787,
                                    "officeId": 100013449,
                                    "address1": "address1",
                                    "address2": "",
                                    "address3": "",
                                    "address4": "",
                                    "addressTown": "addressTown",
                                    "addressPostCode": "addressPostCode",
                                    "tel": "tel",
                                    "fax": "fax",
                                    "responsibilities": "responsibilities"
                                },
                                {
                                    "__metadata": {
                                        "id": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Contacts(id=64085,jobId=1000105448)",
                                        "uri": "http://www.bradinsight.com/ALFAPI/AlfWebApi/Contacts(id=64085,jobId=1000105448)",
                                        "type": "AlfWebApiInfrastructure.Poco.Contact"
                                    },
                                    "id": 64085,
                                    "jobId": 1000105448,
                                    "mask": 67108863,
                                    "name": "name",
                                    "jobtitle": "jobtitle",
                                    "email": "email",
                                    "companyType": "companyType",
                                    "companyId": 1787,
                                    "officeId": 100013449,
                                    "address1": "address1",
                                    "address2": "",
                                    "address3": "",
                                    "address4": "",
                                    "addressTown": "addressTown",
                                    "addressPostCode": "addressPostCode",
                                    "tel": "tel",
                                    "fax": "fax",
                                    "responsibilities": "responsibilities"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": 100013449,
                        "companyId": 1787,
                        "addressLine1": "addressLine1",
                        "addressLine2": "",
                        "addressLine3": "",
                        "addressLine4": "",
                        "addressLine5": "addressLine5",
                        "postCode": "postCode",
                        "regionId": "regionId",
                        "countyId": "countyId",
                        "tvAreaId": "L",
                        "telephone": "telephone",
                        "fax": "fax8",
                        "countryId": "countryId",
                        "email": "email",
                        "isdn": null,
                        "mask": 66060287
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        
               

        $(document).ready(function () {


            //var parsed = JSON.parse(varJson);

            alert(varJson);

        

        });

    </script>
```

I tried using this:

```
$.each(varJson, function (index, item) {
              alert(item);

                });
```

But it just says object in my alert.

Comment: That is not JSON, it's a JavaScript "object literal".  It's already "parsed" - I think you meant "traverse".

Comment: @Alnitak Sorry I mean traverse because I want to see the contents of my object literal in either an alert or console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
function traverse(jsonObj) {
  if( typeof jsonObj == "object" ) {
    $.each(jsonObj, function(k,v) {
        traverse(v);
    });
  }
  else {
    alert(jsonObj);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   traverse(varJson);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/hXEr8/

with reference of [Traverse all the Nodes of a JSON Object Tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: @nickgowdy You should really embrace the power of the console. alerts are so 1980

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse it in your example.

Use `console.log` instead of `alert` and you will the the object in your web inspector.

---

If you do want to `alert` do something like this

`alert(varJson.d.results[0].__metadata.id)`

Comment: When I use $.each to loop through my JSON I get LOG: [object Object]. This is when I use  $.each(varJson, function (index, item) {
                console.log(item);

                });

Comment: What browser are you using?

No need to loop in chrome or firebug