# Java Objects to JSON, parse using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, gson

I am trying to send an array of pojo's as a response to an ajax call.

Inside of my pojo, I have the following toString():

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return "Expense [period=" + period + ", description=" + description + 
               ", category="+ category + ", subCategory="+subCategory+", "
               + "amount="+amount+", store="+store+"]";
}
```

Then, inside of my doGet method, I build up the arraylist of pojos, and am trying to write them out, using:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(expensesForPeriod);
    out.write(json);
```

Where expensesForPeriod is an arraylist of expense objects.

Is this the correct way to send an arraylist of json objects?

On the javascript side, how would I convert the json string to an array of objects, and iterate over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use @Expose before each of your instance members in the class definition, then call the Gson file on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

For java side:

you shouldn't override toString method, just need to use Gson to parse object to json string

For javascript side:

you can follow this tutorial: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript/722676#722676)