# Angular/JS: Json String to object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Have problem with converting string to object.
I'm getting from the server array of object and some of these objects contains other objects. Problem is that JS reads inner object like a string.

Data structure:

```
[
{
    name: String("Name1"),
    key: String("name1"),
    value: String("some text")
},
{
    name: String("Name2"),
    key: String("name2"),
    value: [
        {
            name: String("Object1"),
            key: String("object1"),
            value: [    
                {
                    name: String("Object1 Name3"),
                    key: String("object1.name3"),
                    value: Object()
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: String("Name4"),
            key: String("name4"),
            value: String()
        },
    ]
},
{
    name: String("Name5"),
    key: String("name5"),
    value: Number("44")
}
]
```

Object with **Name2** contains other other object like value.

Problem that when I'm trying to display this object tree with Angular object with name ** Object1 Name3** is a string.

How I can convert all data that I'm getting from the server to OBJECT?

This object tree can have up to 5 nested objects and check value of each of them not a solution for me.

Comment: You've done something wrong there: `{[]}`. You can't have an array like that, JS objects are key:value pairs. Remove the curly braces `{}` from all the `value:` values. NB the prototype of strings built with `new String()` is `Object`, not `String`

Comment: That was misspelled only here, data structure is correct.

Comment: + Yeah you can't expect a JSON obj to be something else than a `String`. You need to parse it before with [`JSON.parse(myJSONfile)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @Tyblitz, yep, but the problem with that solution that it converts only top level object but if I have an object like value of other object it still string.

Comment: That's not true, I've done it successfully before. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript

Comment: Get rid of all the `String("foo")` and `Object()` stuff and just use primitive/literal strings and objects as values. Then use `JSON.stringify(myfoo)` and `JSON.parse('jsonStructure')`. You lose more than you're trying to gain by trying to use those value types in that json structure. So - instead of `name: String("name1")`, just do `name: "name1"` -- or instead of `value: Object()`, just do `value: {}`.

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to work with jsons in angular. Use `angular.toJson` and `angular.fromJson`instead. `angular.toJson` escapes unnecesary `$$` characters.

Comment: @czwek: It doesn't escape characters - it ignored properties whose name starts with `$$`.