# Match values in nested object to corresponding knockout bindings?

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js

Let's say I have a list of knockout bindings placed in a nested/namespaced object, resembling this:

```
var bindings = {
    event: {
        eventid: ko.observable(),
        office: ko.observable(),

        employee: {
            name: ko.observable(),
            group: ko.observable()
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Now let's say there are a number of different sets of data that might be loaded into this - so one does an ajax query and gets a JSON result like this:

```
{
    "defaults": {
        "event": {
            "eventid": 1234,

            "employee": {
                "name": "John Smith"
            }
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that not every binding has a default value - but all defaults are mapped to a binding. What I want to do is read the defaults into whatever knockout binding they correspond to.

There are definitely ways to [traverse a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript) and read its values. Adding an extra argument to that example, I can keep track of the default's full key (eg event.employee.name). Where I'm getting stumped is taking the `default`'s key and using it to target the associated knockout binding. Obviously, even if i have `key = "event.employee.name"`, `bindings.key` doesn't reference what I want. I can only think of using `eval()`, and that leaves me with a bad taste in my mouth.

How would one go about using a key to reference the same location in a different object? Perhaps knockout provides a way to auto-map an object to its bindings, and I've just overlooked it? Any insight would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at the [Knockout Mapping Plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which will do most of what you want to do.  If that doesn't workout then you can turn your `bindings` object into a series of constructor functions that accepts a data parameter.  Something like

```js
var Employee = function (data){
 var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observbale(data.name || '');
   self.group = ko.observable(data.group);
};

var Event = function(data){
 var self = this;
   self.eventid = ko.observable(data.id || 0);
   self.office = ko.observable(data.office || '');
   self.employee = ko.observable(new Employee(data.employee));
};


var bindings = function(data){
    var self = this;
   self.event = ko.observable(new Event(data));
}
```

Comment: Huh, well look at that. That's clever, I never thought to stick a function inside an observable. Wish I could +2 this!

Answer (score 0):

I'll be putting Nathan Fisher's solution into a future update, but I wanted to share the fix I found for now as well. Each time the `defaults` object recurses, I simply pass the corresponding bindings object instead of tracking the entire keypath.

```
var setToDefaults = function(data){
    loopDefaults(data.defaults, bindings);
};

var loopDefaults = function(defaults, targ){
    for(var d in defaults){
        if(defaults.hasOwnProperty(d) && defaults[d]!==null){
            if(typeof(defaults[d])=="object"){
                loopDefaults(defaults[d], targ[d]);
            }else{
                // defaults[d] is a value - set to corresponding knockout binding
                targ[d](defaults[d]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```