# XML to JSON conversion: empty array instead of empty string

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm using the library net.sf.json to convert an XML to a JSON. 
This is the code I wrote:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Desktop\\TestXML.xml");

XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();

JSON json = xmlSerializer.readFromStream(fis);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.add(json);

JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
root.element("WSJson", jsonArray);
```

I noticed that if the XML contains empty tags, they are transformed in empty arrays.

Example: given this xml

```
<WSJson>
    <Tipo_Operazione>I</Tipo_Operazione>
    <Codice_Prestazione>SW1</Codice_Prestazione>
    <Codice_Intervento></Codice_Intervento>
    <Nome/>
</WSJson>
```

the output is

```
{
    "WSJson": [{
        "Tipo_Operazione": "I",
        "Codice_Prestazione": "SW1",
        "Codice_Intervento": [],
        "Nome": []
    }]
}
```

Instead, I would like to have

```
{
    "WSJson": [{
        "Tipo_Operazione": "I",
        "Codice_Prestazione": "SW1",
        "Codice_Intervento": "",
        "Nome": ""
    }]
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need XMLSerialiser to read from file, instead you could use FileReader and `XML.toJSONObject()` to convert XML string to JsonObject?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String xml = null;
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Desktop\\TestXML.xml")))  {
        String readLine =null;
        while((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
            xml += readLine; 
        }
    }
    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong in traversing the JSON object in order to replace the empty arrays with empty strings? It is explained here how to do it:

[Traverse all the Nodes of a JSON Object Tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript)