# Recursively find keys on an object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object structured like this;

```
brand: {
  group: {
    subGroup: {
       items: []
    },
    otherSub: {
       items: []
    }
  }
}
```

Given an array of keys ['brand', 'group', 'newGroup', 'newSubGroup'] I want to split the keys into found and missing keys. So for the structure above I should get back;

```
present = ['brand', 'group']
missing = ['newGroup', 'newSubGroup']
```

I'm using ES6 and have lodash available, but struggling to find a clean way to produce this.

This is not to just check existence, it's recursively find the keys and return those present and the remaining ones.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that. I'm trying to find the cleanest way to work recursively through the object and split the array into the keys found and those that are not present.

Comment: Maybe overkill but have you seen [this object diffing package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff)? I've used it before and I've found it useful.

Comment: Also if you're struggling to find a clean way to do it, could you include the "not clean" way that you've been able to do it?

Comment: I've not got a working version to include.

Comment: I've not selected an answer because I ended up going in a different direction which made this unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty sketchy way that works.

```js
const find = (keys, obj) => {
  const string = JSON.stringify(obj);
  return keys.reduce(({ present, missing }, key) => {
    const match = string.match(new RegExp(`"${key}":`));
    if (match) {
      present.push(key);
    } else {
      missing.push(key);
    }
    return { present, missing };
  }, { present: [], missing: [] });
}
```

Comment: I quite like the terseness of this, but the JSON.stringify disturbs me a little. I guess that's what you meant by sketchy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function made for you ;)

```
var getAttrs = function(obj) {
  return [].concat.apply([], Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 
    var results = [key]
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(results, getAttrs(obj[key]))
    }
    return results
  }))
}
```

It return the list of properties and children properties.

```
getAttrs({brand: {
  group: {
    subGroup: {
       items: []
    },
    otherSub: {
       items: []
    }
  }
}})

> ["brand", "group", "subGroup", "items", "otherSub", "items"]
```

And you can use it like so:

```
var lookingFor = ['brand', 'group', 'newGroup', 'newSubGroup']
var existings = getAttrs(obj)

var missings = []
var presents = []

lookingFor.forEach(attr => {
  if (existings.indexOf(attr) === -1) {
    missings.push(attr)
  } else { 
    presents.push(attr)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var toFind = ['brand', 'group', 'newGroup', 'newSubGroup'],
        found = [];

    var o = {
        brand: {
            group: {
                subGroup: {
                    items: []
                },
                otherSub: {
                    items: []
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //called with every property and its value
    function process(key,value) {
        var i = toFind.indexOf(key);
        if(i !== -1){
          found.push(key);
          toFind.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    
    function traverse(o,func) {
        if(!toFind.length) return;
        for (var i in o) {
            func.apply(this,[i,o[i]]);  
            if (o[i] !== null && typeof(o[i])=="object") {
                //going one step down in the object tree!!
                traverse(o[i],func);
            }
        }
    }
    
    traverse(o,process);

    console.log(found); // present
    console.log(toFind); // absent
```

Traverse method taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/722732/1335165

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to recursively get unique keys from a nested object, then filtered the array of all the keys you mentioned checking which were present in the result of my function.

```js
var thisObject = {
 brand: {
    group: {
      subGroup: {
          items: []
      },
      otherSub: {
          items: []
      }
        }
   }
};

var arr_full =  ['brand', 'group', 'newGroup', 'newSubGroup'] ;

var key_array = [];

function addToKeyArray( key_array, object ){
 
    for( var key in object ){
    
     // only get unique keys
     if( key_array.indexOf( key ) === -1 ){
         key_array.push( key );
        }
    
     // concat the result of calling this function recurrsively on object[key]
     key_array.concat( addToKeyArray( key_array, object[key] ) ); 
    }
    
    return key_array;
}


var test = addToKeyArray( [], thisObject );

var missing = arr_full.filter( function( el ) {
  return test.indexOf( el ) < 0;
});

console.log( test );
console.log( missing )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function using `for...in` loop inside another function and return object as result..

```js
var obj = {"brand":{"group":{"subGroup":{"items":[]},"otherSub":{"items":[]}}}}
var keys =  ['brand', 'group', 'newGroup', 'newSubGroup'] ;

function findKeys(data, keys) {
  keys = keys.slice();
  
  function findPresent(data, keys) {
    var result = []
    
    for(var i in data) {
      if(typeof data[i] == 'object') result.push(...findPresent(data[i], keys))
      var index = keys.indexOf(i);
      if(index != -1) result.push(...keys.splice(index, 1))
    }
    
    return result
  }
  
  return {present: findPresent(data, keys), missing: keys}
}

console.log(findKeys(obj, keys))
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep things clean and readable you can use "for in", inside a nested function for your recursion.

```js
function recur(obj) {
  let preMiss = {
    present: [],
    missing: []
  }
  let root = traverse => {
    for (let key in traverse) {
      if (Array.isArray(traverse[key].items)) {
        preMiss.missing.push(key);
      }
      if (typeof traverse[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(traverse[key].items)) {
        preMiss.present.push(key);
        root(traverse[key])
      }
    }
  }
  root(obj);
  return preMiss;
}

const object = {
  brand: {
    group: {
      subGroup: {
        items: []
      },
      otherSub: {
        items: []
      }
    }
  }
}


console.log(Object.entries(recur(object)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is a bit older, I want to present a rather short solution to the problem.

```
const recursivelyGetKeys = obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => typeof obj[key] === 'object' 
? [...recursivelyGetKeys(obj[key]), key] : [key]).reduce((p, c) => [...p, ...c], [])
```

This function will return all keys in the object, so a call to the array `arr` with

```
const arr = {
  brand: {
    group: {
       subGroup: {
          items: []
       },
       otherSub: {
          items: []
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

will output:

```
const keys = recursivelyGetKeys(arr) // = ["items", "subGroup", "items", "otherSub", "group", "brand"]
```

Now to find the intersection set of this and `find = ['brand', 'group', 'newGroup', 'newSubGroup']`, do:

```
const found = keys.filter(key => find.some(val === key))
const missing = keys.filter(key => find.every(val !== key))
```