# Toggle the Boolean value of a nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to toggle the Boolean value of this nested input object

```
var obj = { a: { b: { c: false } } };
```

in an efficient way so that `obj` is output as:

```
{ a: { b: { c: true } } };
```

I am using:

```
Object.keys(obj).map(function(k, i) {
    // Check if obj is Boolean else if object nest again till I find the Boolean value and toggle it.
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traverse all the Nodes of a JSON Object Tree with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722668/traverse-all-the-nodes-of-a-json-object-tree-with-javascript)

Comment: I suspect your question is leaving out details we need in order to help you. The literal answer is `obj.a.b.c = true`, but ... ?

Answer (score 2):

You could build a new opbject and take either an object with a recursive call or a value and return the toggled value.

```js
const
    toggle = object => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v && typeof v === 'object' ? toggle(v) : !v])
    );

var object = { a: { b: { c: false } } };

console.log(toggle(object));
```