# How to display treeview component in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

Can someone help me with render a treeview in vuetify
im have a response as like this
in this situation im using a vuetify framework

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Test",
    "parent_id": 0,
    "image": "gVtHmE4tN18Y.png",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Test2",
        "parent_id": 4,
        "image": "XBpqGq6CinOm.png",
        "parent": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Test3",
            "parent_id": 6,
            "image": "MNI3TmNXI1V5.png",
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and i dont know how display this response in treeview
im try to use many solutions but im dont have any result
This is what i found out is
if someone know how to do this it will be nice
thanks for help

Comment: only show `Test`? no way to expand the tree?

Comment: you should read using v-for here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<v-treeview/>`, by default, loads the ['children'](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#api) property, if there's any. However, on your example, we can see that on the first children, it has no 'children' property. But 'parent' property is present, and you want to treat it as a children too.

Solution: You can create a computed variable that traverses all nodes, check if it has a 'parent' property, and add 'children' property that has the same value as the 'parent' property. *(I'm gonna use this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/722676/9183405) for traversing the items).*

```html
<v-treeview :items="modifiedItems"/>
```

```js
data: () => ({
  items: [{...}]
}),

computed: {
  modfiedItems() {
    // let's clone the items so we won't pollute the original data.
    const clonedItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items));
    this.traverse(clonedItems);
    return clonedItems;
  }
},
methods: {
  // reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/722676/9183405
  traverse(items) {
    // check if the node is an object or array
    if (items !== null && typeof items === "object") {
      Object.entries(items).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        // check if the item/node has a 'parent' property
        if (key === "parent") {
          items.children = value; 
        }
        this.traverse(value);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

So now, if the a node/item has a 'children' or 'parent' property to it, it will still be loaded on the treeview. If both property is present, the 'children' will be the one used.

Here is a sample code [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mcnulty-8le1b?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).

Comment: You're welcome. Goodluck!